# Firebase Permission Denied after Authentication

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I need help with Firebase for Unity.

I'm getting `Firebase Database error: Permission denied` when I try to write (or read) from the database after authenticating with Google (it works fine with Facebook) though after restarting the app it lets me read and write and no longer throws the error.

It started happening recently because it worked fine a week ago. My rules are also correctly setup (It works the second time so that's not the problem. It also works fine with Facebook).

I am using `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged` and it even throws the error in there. The `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser` variable ***is*** getting populated. I don't think anything's wrong with the authentication flow because it works the second time I launch the app (Firebase is already logged in, I just re-authenticate with google and call the SignInWithCredentials method) for some reason.

Should I add some sort of delay after the authentication? Or is it something else? Did I miss an update?

I have read the other questions and none of them worked.

MainMenu.cs

```
public IEnumerator CompleteGoogleLogin()
{
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        try
        {
            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN] USER: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FireDatabase.CurrentUser, Formatting.Indented));
            var providerData = FireDatabase.ProviderData; 
            newUser.UpdateUserProfileAsync(new UserProfile()
            {
                DisplayName = newUser.DisplayName,
                PhotoUrl = providerData.PhotoUrl
            }).ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
                    Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN] TASK IS FAULTED");
                    return;
                }
                if (t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
                    Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN] TASK IS CANCELED");
                    return;
                }
                StartCoroutine(PostGoogleLogin());
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN]: " + e.Message  + " StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                Debug.LogError("[COMPLETE_GOOGLE_LOGIN] INNER_EXCEPTION: " + e.InnerException.Message + " StackTrace: " + e.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    });
}

private IEnumerator PostGoogleLogin()
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => FireDatabase.IsLoggedIn);
    // 09-14 22:54:02.208 28521 28742 W Unity   : 01/02/0001 17:49:01 [Warn] RepoOperation: setValue at /users/XjGPJlZ45kPhVijKtxCOwA2xmHC2/name failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
    FireDatabase.UsersDatabase.Child(FireDatabase.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("name").SetValueAsync(FireDatabase.CurrentUser.DisplayName).ContinueWith((o) => {

        if (o.IsFaulted)
        {
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   : [POST_GOOGLE_LOGIN] EXCEPTIONS: [
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :   {
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "ClassName": "Firebase.Database.DatabaseException",
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "Message": "Firebase Database error: Permission denied",
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "Data": null,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "InnerException": null,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "HelpURL": null,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "StackTraceString": null,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "ExceptionMethod": null,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "HResult": -2146233088,
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :     "Source": null
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   :   }
            // 09-14 22:54:02.276 28521 28545 E Unity   : ]
            Debug.LogError("[POST_GOOGLE_LOGIN] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
            Debug.LogError("[POST_GOOGLE_LOGIN] TASK IS FAULTED");
            return;
        }
        if (o.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("[POST_GOOGLE_LOGIN] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
            Debug.LogError("[POST_GOOGLE_LOGIN] TASK IS CANCELED");
            return;
        }
        StartCoroutine(DownloadProfilePicture(FireDatabase.ProviderData.PhotoUrl.AbsoluteUri + "?sz=" + (int) mainMenuProfilePicture.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x));
    });
}
```

FireDatabase.cs

```
public static class FireDatabase
{
    .....
    public static FirebaseUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentUser != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser.UserId) && CurrentUser.ProviderData.Count() > 1;
        }
    }

    public static IUserInfo ProviderData
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsLoggedIn)
                return null;

            var providers = CurrentUser.ProviderData.GetEnumerator();
            while (providers.MoveNext())
            {
                if (providers.Current.ProviderId == Provider.Google || providers.Current.ProviderId == Provider.Facebook)
                    return providers.Current;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static DatabaseReference UsersDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("users");
        }
    }
    .....
    static FireDatabase()
    {
        var serverDate = GetServerDate();
        LeaderboardDatabase.Child(leaderboardType).Child(serverDate).KeepSynced(true);
        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsLoggedIn)
                {
                    //09-14 22:32:43.870 25148 25409 W Unity   : 01/02/0001 17:49:01 [Warn] SyncTree: Listen at /users/XjGPJlZ45kPhVijKtxCOwA2xmHC2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
                    UsersDatabase.Child(CurrentUser.UserId).KeepSynced(true);
                    Debug.LogError("[FIRE_DATABASE] USER AUTH STATE CHANGED");
                    LeaderboardDatabase.Child(leaderboardType).Child(serverDate).ValueChanged += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("LEADERBOARDS VALUE CHANGED");
                        GetRanking();
                        GetLeaderboards();
                    };

                    UsersDatabase.Child(CurrentUser.UserId).ValueChanged += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("USER_PROFILE VALUE CHANGED");
                        GetPlayerProfile(); //<- This is being called when the StateChanged event is raised by firebase AFTER authentication
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Debug.LogError("[FIRE_DATABASE] " + x.Message + " StackTrace: " + x.StackTrace);
                if (x.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("[FIRE_DATABASE] INNER EXCEPTION: " + x.InnerException.Message + " StackTrace: " + x.InnerException.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    .....

    public static void GetPlayerProfile()
    {
        if (CurrentUser != null)
            //CurrentUser is not null, so it outputs the thing
            Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] USER: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CurrentUser, Formatting.Indented));
        else
            return;

        UsersDatabase.Child(CurrentUser.UserId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith((t)=>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   : [GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] EXCEPTIONS: [
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :   {
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "ClassName": "Firebase.Database.DatabaseException",
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "Message": "Firebase Database error: Permission denied",
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "Data": null,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "InnerException": null,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "HelpURL": null,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "StackTraceString": null,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "ExceptionMethod": null,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "HResult": -2146233088,
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :     "Source": null
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   :   }
                //09-14 22:32:44.088 25148 25178 E Unity   : ]
                Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
                Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] TASK IS FAULTED");
            }
            else if (t.IsCanceled) 
            {
                Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
                Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] TASK IS CANCELED");
            }
            else if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                try
                {

                    DataSnapshot snapshot = t.Result;
                    PlayerData pd = new PlayerData();

                    if (t.Result.ChildrenCount != 0)
                        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue(), pd);
                    Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] TASK IS " + t.Result.GetType());
                    Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] RAWJSON: " + snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
                    ProfileChange?.Invoke(pd);
                    Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] PROFILE_CHANGE " + (ProfileChange == null));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("[GET_PLAYER_PROFILE] EXCEPTIONS: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t.Exception.InnerExceptions, Formatting.Indented));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FIREBASE RULES:

```
{
    "rules": 
    {
        ".read": "false",
        ".write": "false",
        "users":{
            ".read":"false",
            ".write":"false",
            "$user_id":{
                ".read":"auth!=null && $user_id == auth.uid",
                ".write":"auth!=null && $user_id == auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you may be trying to read from or write to the database before authenticating, but without any code, it's hard to say. Please update your question to include the code for authenticating, as well as the code where you're getting the `permission denied` error

Comment: No, I am reading/writing AFTER authentication and the proof is that the `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser` is populating BEFORE I make *any* queries

Comment: I am also querying AFTER `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged` (All the methods that query are bound to "ValueChanged" event after that delegate is called)

Comment: Please see this entry on writing a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, updated post with code

Comment: If you don't mind a question from someone who doesn't know C#:  I see references to `FireDatabase.CurrentUser`.  `CurrentUser` is a static field of your `FireDatabase` class, right? But in the code you posted for `FireDatabase`, I don't see the declaration of `CurrentUser`.  Can you add that?  I don't see `CurrentUser` set anywhere in the code, but it must be set somewhere, because your debug output shows a value for UID.

Comment: Also, consider adding a log statement in `CompleteGoogleLogin()` to output `newUser.UserId` so you can compare it with the value of `FireDatabase.CurrentUser.UserId` logged in that method.  I have concerns that they may not be the same.

Comment: Added CurrentUser

Comment: I've verified that they are indeed both same

Comment: We recently fixed a bug in the 4.2.0 SDK where auth tokens were not being propagated to the Database component.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.2.0  I recommend checking out our latest release and contacting our support team if it doesn't resolve your issue.